# Django query with simple arithmetic among model fields and comparison with field from another model

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

(All code below is a simplified representation of the actual code).

If I have the following Django models: -

```
class Material(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=110)

class OrderDetail(models.Model):
    material = models.ForeignKey(Material)
    order_quantity = models.IntegerField()
    quantity_delivered = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_open = models.BooleanField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField()

class MaterialRequirement(models.Model):
    material = models.ForeignKey(Material)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

I have with me an instance of the `MaterialRequirement` model, let's call it `material_requirement`. I am trying to retrieve `OrderDetail` objects which satisfy the following criteria:-

```
1. material = material_requirement.material

2. is_open = True

3. is_active = True

4. order_quantity > quantity_delivered

5. material_requirement.quantity <= order_quantity - quantity_delivered
```

My question is how do I incorporate the 5th selection criteria in my ORM query below.

```
order_details = OrderDetail.objects.select_related('material').filter(material=material_requirement.material,
                                                                    is_open=True,
                                                                    is_active=True,
                                                                    order_quantity__gt=F('quantity_delivered'))
```

Comment: Apologize to all - point no. 5 should be material_requirement.quantity <= order_quantity - quantity_delivered and not material_requirement.quantity >= order_quantity - quantity_delivered. I have corrected the question. Again, apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
order_details = (OrderDetail.objects.select_related('material')
                 .filter(material=material_requirement.material,
                         is_open=True,
                         is_active=True,
                         order_quantity__gt=F('quantity_delivered'),
                         quantity_delivered__gte=F('order_quantity') - material_requirement.quantity,
                         )
)
```

Comment: There was a mistake in my question, please see the edit notes. Anyway, this is what I went with - blame my mental spaghetti for getting confused. I ended up using 

order_details = OrderDetail.objects.select_related('material').filter(material=material_requirement.material,
                                                                    is_open=True,
                                                                    is_active=True,
                                                                    order_quantity__gte=F('quantity_delivered') + material_requirement.quantity)

Comment: You might want to update your answer to reflect the rectified question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
order_details = order_detail.extra(where=["order_quantity - quantity_delivered <= %d" % material_requirement.quantity]))
```