# How to execute arithmetic operations between Model fields in django

Tags: python, django

**Prologue:**

This is a question arising often in SO:

- [Subtracting two annotated columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17374467/subtracting-two-annotated-columns)
- [Django query with simple arithmetic among model fields and comparison with field from another model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15586052/django-query-with-simple-arithmetic-among-model-fields-and-comparison-with-field)
- [Django Aggregation: Summation of Multiplication of two fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165636/django-aggregation-summation-of-multiplication-of-two-fields)

And can also be applied here:

- [Django F expression on datetime objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43890131/django-f-expression-on-datetime-objects/43890979#43890979)

I have composed an example on SO Documentation but since the Documentation will get shut down on August 8, 2017, I will follow the suggestion of [this widely upvoted and discussed meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation/354302#354302) and transform my example to a self-answered post.

Of course, I would be more than happy to see any different approach as well!!

---

**Question:**

Assume the following model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    number_1 = models.IntegerField()
    number_2 = models.IntegerField()
    date_1 = models.DateTimeField()
    date_2 = models.DateTimeField()
```

How can I execute arithmetic operations between fields of this model?

For example, how can I find:

- The product of `number_1` and `number_2` of a MyModel object?
- How to filter items where `date_2` is 10 or more days older than `date_1`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[`F()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) expressions can be used to execute arithmetic operations (`+`, `-`, `*` etc.) among model fields, in order to define an algebraic lookup/connection between them.

> An `F()` object **represents the value** of a model field or annotated column. It makes it possible to refer to model field values and perform database operations using them **without actually having to pull them out of the database** into Python memory.

let's tackle the issues then:

- **The product of two fields:**

  ```
  result = MyModel.objects.all().annotate(prod=F('number_1') * F('number_2'))
  ```

  Now every item in `result` has an extra column named 'prod' which contains the product of `number_1` and `number_2` of each item respectively.
- **Filter by day difference:**

  ```
  from datetime import timedelta

  result = MyModel.objects.all().annotate(
               delta=F('date_2') - F('date_1')
           ).filter(delta__gte=timedelta(days=10))
  ```

  Now the items in `result` are those from `MyModel` whose `date_2` is 10 or more days older than `date_1`. These items have a new column named `delta` with that difference.
- **A different case:**

  We can even use `F()` expressions to make arithmetic operations on annotated columns as follows:

  ```
  result = MyModel.objects.all()
                          .annotate(sum_1=Sum('number_1'))
                          .annotate(sum_2=Sum('number_2'))
                          .annotate(sum_diff=F('sum_2') - F('sum_1'))
  ```

Comment: In case some one is facing issues : from django.db.models import F

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: `from django.db.models import F`

Step 2: `from datetime import timedelta`

Step 3: You may then apply the F operator in your queryset as follows:

```
MyModel.objects.all().annotate(
         date_diff=F('date_2') - F('date_1')
     ).filter(date_diff__gte=timedelta(days=10)
)
```