# Django Admin, sort with custom function

Tags: python, django, sorting, django-admin

How can I sort a column in Django admin by some simple custom method?
 
(All the answers I got through was by using `annotate` but I don't know how to use it my case).

Assume the model

```
class Shots(models.Model):    
    hits = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    all = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

In admin site I would like to sort by `hits to all` ratio:

```
class ShotAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['ratio']

    def ratio(self, obj):
        return obj.hits / obj.all * 100
```

I know the `ratio` is not a field in DB thus simple `ratio.admin_order_field = 'ratio'` won't work and I need to somehow append this as a field but I have no idea how.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By following:

- The accepted answer to this post:
  [Django admin: how to sort by one of the custom list_display fields that has no database field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168475/django-admin-how-to-sort-by-one-of-the-custom-list-display-fields-that-has-no-d)
- The
  [How to execute arithmetic operations between Model fields in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45593440/how-to-execute-arithmetic-operations-between-model-fields-in-django?answertab=votes#tab-top) 
  (*Disclaimer:* I have composed that Q&A style example)

We can compose a solution to your problem:

```
from django.db.models import F

class ShotsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('get_ratio',)

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(ShotsAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        qs = qs.annotate(ratio=F('hits') * 100 / F('all'))
        return qs

    def get_ratio(self, obj):
        return obj.ratio

    get_ratio.admin_order_field = 'ratio'
```

Explanation:

- The `get_queryset` method will annotate a new field named `ratio` to
  your queryset. That field's value is the application of your ratio function on the `hits` and `all` fields.
- The `get_ratio` function returns the aforementioned field from a queryset instance.
- Finally: `get_ratio.admin_order_field = 'ratio'` sets the `ratio` field as the ordering field for your queryset on the admin panel.

Comment: Many thanks, it all works great if  applied with the following modifications: 1) call `super` on proper class i.e.`ShotsAdmin`, 2) `ratio=(F('hits') * 100 / F('all'))` as it truncates to the nearest integer

Comment: Good to know @micsza I will edit my answer accordingly!