# How to do arthimetic operations on database values in django

Tags: django

I have:

```
Prof:AssociateProf:AssistantProf = x:y:z
```

in database and I have to do these operations:

```
x/(x+y+z) :  y/(x+y+z) :  z/(x+y+z)
```

in django.

Can anyone help me on this? Models.py is :

```
class Show(models.Model) :
Total = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
Prof = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
AssociateProf = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
AssistantProf = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
ResearchScholar = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
MTech = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute arithmetic operations between Model fields in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45593440/how-to-execute-arithmetic-operations-between-model-fields-in-django)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow . You could've added more details to your question.

You could access model's data using Django's Queryset and write custom functions in respective views and show them in respecive Views(html/templates) .

Refer to [DjangoQuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/) for documentation about Django Queryset

and this was answered in another post : [How to execute arithmetic operations between Model fields in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45593440/how-to-execute-arithmetic-operations-between-model-fields-in-django)

Comment: If you think a question is a duplicate then you should flag it as such.

Comment: I tried like this: a = Show.objects.all
    for k in a :
        p = int(k.Prof) + int(k.AssociateProf)  + int(k.AssistantProf).   I didn't get and I dont understand how to get the individual elements . Can u pls help me on this