# Intersecting multipolygon layer with polygon in GeoDjango

Tags: python, django, postgresql, postgis, geodjango

I have a `Region` GeoDjango model (deriving from `django.contrib.gis.db.models.Model`), with a `geom` field, which is a `django.contrib.gis.db.models.MultiPolygonField`.

I'd like to compute the intersection of this model (representing a set of polygonal regions stored in PostGIS) with a GeoJSON polygonal "query":

```py
from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSGeometry

query = GEOSGeometry(
    '{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-80.983786,43.929011],[-80.511513,43.778458],[-80.291852,44.079184],[-80.775108,44.232127],[-80.983786,43.929011]]]}'
)
```

I tried many things:

```py
results = Region.objects.all().intersection(query)
```

or

```py
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import Intersection

results = Intersection(Region.objects.all(), query)
```

but it seems I don't have the right approach.

Note that I do not want to simply compute the subset of regions which intersect with the query, but rather their exact intersection (in other words the resulting set of polygons should have the exact same shape as the query).

Comment: Hey @cjauvin, I was making a pass through my answers and I was wondering, did you find this answer helpful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially we need to `annotate` the `intersection` (if any) of each `Region`'s `geom` with the given `query`. Doing so with a DB query look like this:

```
from django.db.models import F
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import Intersection
from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSGeometry

query = GEOSGeometry(
    '{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-80.983786,43.929011],[-80.511513,43.778458],[-80.291852,44.079184],[-80.775108,44.232127],[-80.983786,43.929011]]]}'
) 

results = Region.objects.filter(geom__intersects=query).annotate(
    intersection_geom=Intersection(F('geom'), query)
)
```

**Query Explanation:**

1. Filter the `Regions` that **intersect** the `query`, using the [`intersects`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#intersects) spatial lookup.
2. Calculate the result of [`Intersection`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/gis/functions/#intersection) between a Region's `geom` field and the `query`, using the [`F()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) expression to access the `geom` (an explanation on `F()` usage can be found in my Q&A example: [How to execute arithmetic operations between Model fields in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45593440/how-to-execute-arithmetic-operations-between-model-fields-in-django/))
3. [`annotate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate) the calculated Intersection into each corresponding `Region` as a field named `intersection_geom`.

After the query execution, the `results` will contain each `Region` that intersects the `query` geom, with the `intersection_geom` field containing the exact geometry of the corresponding intersection.